# Using df.shape I get wrong number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 800 rows; when I print it, the last index of this dataframe is 799 (so exactly 800 rows) but when I get its shape (df.shape) the result is 789 rows. Could someone explain me how is this possible? How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please create a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

Your DataFrame has 789 rows. If you dropped 10 rows at some point, the index will not be changed so that ten values should be missing.
Try

```
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

and see whether the last index is 788.

Comment: Thank you! Now I get the correct last index.